# Postgres docker has unknown user

Tags: postgresql, docker

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: authdb

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Whatever I type in... in the container no user seems to exist:

```
psql -U postgres
```

or

```
psql -U authdb
```

or

```
psql
```

or

```
psql -U root
```

or

```
psql -U test
```

Anyways, you get the idea.

What is the user?

I am using latest version of postgres like you can see in my docker compose file.

Is there a way for me to list the users? Maybe it's a bug in docker postgres?

Comment: I think you have to declare the `POSTGRES_USER` environment variable in your `compose.yml`. See the available variables in the postgres image doc: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
psql -U test --dbname=authdb
```

It seems that if you don't specify the db name it won't work.

I think it's because it thinks the username and db name are one in the same.

Very strange since none the examples I have seen online mention this.

Also, like @hakre has said the default user is `postgres`.

When I did my build the first time I had `test` as username and password.

So this is why in my solution I am using test.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [image description](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres?tab=description#postgres_user), it should be "postgres", more:

> `POSTGRES_USER`
>   This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the ***default user of `postgres`*** will be used.

(emphasis by me)

Comment: In the question I did mention that I tried **postgres**. I have tried other things but nothing works.

Comment: I've seen that, but it still remains the default username and you have not any other configuration for the username in your docker invocation via the compose file posted. I could easily verify it works as documented. It's likely not the username you'd like to learn about (albeit you asked for it).

Comment: Try: `$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres`, then `$ docker exec -it some-postgres psql -U postgres` to verify it's that username with the (local copy of the) postgres image you have in use. Clean up with `$ docker rm -f some-postgres` when you exit the psql shell.

Comment: I had to add the `--dbname=` to make it work. It seems `psql` thinks that the username and db name are one and the same.